# What does "conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch" install?

Tags: anaconda, pytorch

I tried installing PyTorch on my system with not just the `pip install pytorch -c pytorch` command but with `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch` but I see a very long command prompt running since last 2 hours giving a very large outputs.
Is the process going good? I've CUDA 10.2 installed and also tensorflow-gpu and cuDNN too.
I see these arguments being shown.
**Here's the long list of commands running since past 2 hours**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D4p9bfxNHXZfe8PCjc45OPlPZfasxk_4/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please do not put important details regarding your question at the end of a link. Put them *in* your question so they can be easily searched for by future visitors

Comment: @talonmies I tried doing so but those commands exceeded the maximum limit of StackOverflow and I had to link that in my URL.

Comment: "What does <X> install?" is also not a programming question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I understand and I apologise for the same. I just wanted to know how it's different from ```pip install pytorch -c pytorch```. Thanks and apologies.

Comment: @ShashankVRay: Note I said *important* details. Thousands of lines of useless information isn't important. The actual error message is

Answer (score 4):

The *preferred* way of installing PyTorch is through Anaconda, it has some of the common dependencies (packages) pre-installed and saves you a lot of time. Try a clean install of Conda and run:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

The main difference between Anaconda and a vanilla Python installation would be the packages that come pre-installed and the source of those packages. Conda has it's own Python environment, own set of packages and Conda CLI (and a GUI now) to manage the environment.
The conda command can be thought of as pip, but the difference being that conda can install libraries and packages that are not only for Python.

Refer to here for more details: https://www.anaconda.com/understanding-conda-and-pip/

As for your log, I don't see anything *wrong* with it. Just let it do it's job.
If there is an error message I missed on there, let me know and I'll take a look.